# How can I smooth rough latex paint before repainting

Tags: paint-removal

There are several rough areas in the latex paint in my bathroom.  I want to smooth them before repainting but I'm not sure how.  The finish is somewhat shiny (maybe semi-gloss, maybe eggshell).  When I've tried sanding latex paint in the past, it just turned to goo and clogged up the sand paper.  (The paint is recent enough that I'm confident there is no lead in it.)  I'd skim coat with wall compound but I'm afraid it won't stick to the shiny finish.  Stripping seems an extreme solution.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

USG All Purpose joint compound sticks to shiny surfaces. you have to lightly sand the wall first only to prevent bubbling. All Purpose compound has glue in it. It stuck perfectly to my semi-gloss walls. I know this post is old but if anyone else comes by I wanted them to know. I got my information directly from USG

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 1):

Course sandpaper can be the best solution. If you are experiencing clogging of the paper grit then step up to a courser grit. It is probably better to sand latex paint by hand instead of with a power sander to limit the heat buildup and corresponding paint goo.

If you want to go the route of applying the wall compound you could try one of several commercial products that can be wiped over the paint to take off the gloss surface. I have even found a mixture of TSP in hot water to do a decent job of removing some of the gloss on painted surfaces.